# UNET start game with friend by finding their name, Android

Tags: unity, android, unity-networking

There is a game at the google play store called Fun Run 2- Multiplayer Race. I loved its feature to find friends by writing their names, and then to play with them. Is it possible to achieve that with UNET? How?

Another one is called Virtual Table Tennis. There I have a lobby full of people from whom I can choose. Can I achieve that with UNET? How?

Answer (score 1):

I implemented a lobby of sorts by using a middle-man machine that hosts would register sessions with, allowing connecting-clients to scan the well-known middle-man for sessions and connect without needing to know the IP and port of the respective host.

Options then include:
1) An online, well-known server that performs the middle-man role. This would be used to implement a fully networked lobby as you would see in many games
2) A middle-man on the same local network as the clients that either discovers hosts by being well-known (and therefore hosts register sessions with this middle-man) or by discovering them using the low-level API (have a Google - there's a forum post regarding the discovery of hosts using Unity Multiplayer's LLAPI) http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-NetworkDiscovery.html

The middle man could always be running on a host itself, so you don't necessarily need a third wheel